# How can I use data from another remote repository without including it in my repository?

Tags: git, github, repository, devops

I currently have a CI workflow for tests that use data present in my repository. However, since this data is very large, I would like to move it to another remote repo and somehow give my CI tests access to this data from that other repo. One way I could do this is by using git submodules, but that would still force me to include the data in my repo. Is there any way I can use data from another remote repo for my CI tests without including that data in my repo?

Comment: “using git submodules, but that would still force me to include the data in my repo” – Not quite. A submodule is like a link between repositories. While the contents of the submodule can be checked out into your working directory together with your main repository, it has a completely independent commit history. But if the data is fairly constant you might not have to use Git, and could just write a script for your CI system that downloads the data?

Answer (score 1):

Download the data from a local server when you need it.

Suggestions could be to download and unpack a zip file or rsync a directory

Answer (score 0):

If you use two seperate pipines, one for CI and one for CD then you create your artifacts and build outputs in the first and make them available to the deploy pipeline in the second. These don't need to be in the same repo you would declare the external repos as resources to be used within the pipeline.

https://elanderson.net/2020/04/azure-devops-pipelines-use-yaml-across-repos/